# Displaying ListView Data from Database with Newest Results at Top and Oldest at Bottom

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I Currently have a listview which is getting its data from a SQL Lite Database. I can't figure out how to make the data appear with the newest info at the top, and the oldest at the bottom.
Here is my main class which is displaying the listview and my DBAdapter

main:

```
package com.ArielR.Spot;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class main extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

DBAdapter SpotDB;
String Name;
String URL;
String Description;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    openDB();
    if (extras != null) {
        Name= extras.getString("name");
        URL= extras.getString("url");
        Description= extras.getString("description");
        if(Name.equals("") || URL.equals("") || Description.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid Submission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            populateListViewfromDB();
        }
        else{

            populateListViewfromDB();
        }
    }

    }

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    closeDB();
}

private void openDB() {
    SpotDB = new DBAdapter(this);
    SpotDB.open();
    addRow();
    populateListViewfromDB();
}
private void closeDB() {
    SpotDB.close();
}

public void addRow() {
    long newid = SpotDB.insertRow(Name, URL, Description);
    populateListViewfromDB();
}


public void AddNew() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(this, AddNewItem.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}


public void populateListViewfromDB() {
    Cursor cursor = SpotDB.getAllRows();

    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    String[] FromFieldNames= new String[]
            {DBAdapter.KEY_NAME, DBAdapter.KEY_URL, DBAdapter.KEY_DESCRIPTION};
    int[] ToViewIDs= new int[]
            {R.id.Name, R.id.URL, R.id.Description};

    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter =
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    R.layout.row,
                    cursor,
                    FromFieldNames,
                    ToViewIDs
            );

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    list.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            AddNew();
            return true;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

DBAdapter:

```
package com.ArielR.Spot;

 import android.content.ContentValues;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
 import android.util.Log;



public class DBAdapter {

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Constants & Data
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// For logging:
private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

// DB Fields
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final int COL_ROWID = 0;
/*
 * CHANGE 1:
 */
// TODO: Setup your fields here:
public static final String KEY_NAME = "Name";
public static final String KEY_URL = "URL";
public static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "Description";

// TODO: Setup your field numbers here (0 = KEY_ROWID, 1=...)
public static final int COL_NAME = 1;
public static final int COL_URL = 2;
public static final int COL_DESCRIPTION = 3;


public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_URL,               KEY_DESCRIPTION};

// DB info: it's name, and the table we are using (just one).
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "SpotDb";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "main";
// Track DB version if a new version of your app changes the format.
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL =
        "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE
                + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "

        /*
         * CHANGE 2:
         */
                // TODO: Place your fields here!
                // + KEY_{...} + " {type} not null"
                //  - Key is the column name you created above.
                //  - {type} is one of: text, integer, real, blob
                //      (http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)
                //  - "not null" means it is a required field (must be given a value).
                // NOTE: All must be comma separated (end of line!) Last one must have NO comma!!
                + KEY_NAME + " text not null, "
                + KEY_URL + " text not null, "
                + KEY_DESCRIPTION + " text not null"

                // Rest  of creation:
                + ");";

// Context of application who uses us.
private final Context context;

private DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Public methods:
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
    myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

// Open the database connection.
public DBAdapter open() {
    db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

// Close the database connection.
public void close() {
    myDBHelper.close();
}

// Add a new set of values to the database.
public long insertRow(String name, String url, String description) {
    /*
     * CHANGE 3:
     */
    // TODO: Update data in the row with new fields.
    // TODO: Also change the function's arguments to be what you need!
    // Create row's data:
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    initialValues.put(KEY_URL, url);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, description);

    // Insert it into the database.
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

// Delete a row from the database, by rowId (primary key)
public boolean deleteRow(long rowId) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, where, null) != 0;
}

public void deleteAll() {
    Cursor c = getAllRows();
    long rowId = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ROWID);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            deleteRow(c.getLong((int) rowId));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
}

// Return all data in the database.
public Cursor getAllRows() {
    String where = null;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS,
            where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

// Get a specific row (by rowId)
public Cursor getRow(long rowId) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS,
            where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

// Change an existing row to be equal to new data.
public boolean updateRow(long rowId, String name, String url, String description) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;

    /*
     * CHANGE 4:
     */
    // TODO: Update data in the row with new fields.
    // TODO: Also change the function's arguments to be what you need!
    // Create row's data:
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    newValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    newValues.put(KEY_URL, url);
    newValues.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, description);

    // Insert it into the database.
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newValues, where, null) != 0;
}



/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Private Helper Classes:
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/**
 * Private class which handles database creation and upgrading.
 * Used to handle low-level database access.
 */
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
        _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading application's database from version " + oldVersion
                + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data!");

        // Destroy old database:
        _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);

        // Recreate new database:
        onCreate(_db);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `getAllRows()` for the call `db.query()` you can give an `orderBy` parameter. Assuming that the `KEY_ROWID` reflects the order from oldest to newest, the `orderBy` parameter can be `KEY_ROWID + " DESC"`

Comment: Would this take place one of the null parameters or would it add a new parameter?  Could you give an example of the new db.query()?

Comment: @ArielRakovitsky This would replace one of the `null` parameters. You can look in the docs for `SQLiteDatabase.query()` to find out which must be replaced. There are multiple variants of `query()` but only one with exactly 9 parameters.

Comment: Thank you guys so much! Download the app it should be out in about a week named Spot

Answer (score 0):

Get your DB data in a List or a Map and put the list in reverse order in your listview adapter